# How to export the event log from the Console.app into a text file?

Tags: macos, applications, catalina, logs, console

According to tutorials, you'd export your Console.app event log by pressing the "Share" and using e.g. the Mail.app:

https://help.realmacsoftware.com/en/articles/1905631-how-to-save-console-logs-in-os-x

However, I want to export the event log to a plain text file instead of an extension app.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. You can send the logs as a plane text via mail.
   Just press **Cmd-Shift-T** in Mail.app before sending e-mail (or choose Menu -> Format -> **Make Plane Text**).
   This will clear all formatting in hole email and the recipient will receive the logs in proper format.
2. Cmd-A, Cmd-C in Console.app and Cmd-V in an empty text file as it was suggested by Seamus.
3. You can use Terminal.app and directly database were all the logs resides and even do not open Console.app

- To see the logs for your app:

> ```
> log show --predicate 'sender == "the_name_of_your_app"' --style compact
> ```

- To see the logs for the specified time interval:

> ```
> log show --predicate 'sender == "the_name_of_your_app"' --style compact --start '2020-10-07 16:55:00' --end '2020-10-07 16:59:00'
> ```

- To save the logs for the specified time interval into a file to keep/send:

> ```
> log show --predicate 'sender == "the_name_of_your_app"' --style compact --start '2020-10-07 16:55:00' --end '2020-10-07 16:59:00' > your_library.log
> ```

- To see the logs in real time directly in Terminal:

> ```
> log stream --predicate 'sender == "the_name_of_your_app"' --style compact
> ```

Press Ctrl-C to stop capturing process.

Answer (score 1):

Try this while viewing the event log in Console.app:

1. click Edit > Select All to select all the messages on the current screen.
2. click Edit > Copy to copy them to your clipboard

Paste the results to your chosen text editor?

If that doesn't make it for you, please edit your question to provide more details & we'll try to help.